# Correct pattern to define data mode in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

A simple abstract data model to be used by a Vue application, should it be:

`Person.vue`

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String
  }
}
</script>
```

or `Person.js`

```
class Person {
  constructor(props) {
    this.firstName = '';
    this.LastName = '';
  }
}
export default Person;
```

Eventually how to use it from a different component?

```
import Person from './Person';
...
  data () {
    return {
      userA: new Person(),
      userB: Person,
    }
  }
```

Comment: For what it's worth, it looks like you may be reinventing [vuex](http://vuex.vuejs.org) here.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component named "Person.vue".

```
<script>
export default {
name : 'person',
  props: {
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String
  }
}
</script>
```

For use the component in an other ".vue" file, firstly, you have to import the component using : `import Person from './Person';` and then you can use it calling like this : `<person firstName="Toto" lastName="Titi"></person>`

Answer (score 0):

Components must be registered in parent component `components` section or globally with `Vue.component` method to use them. Example:

**Person.vue**

```
<script>
    export default {
       props: {
           firstName: String,
           lastName: String
       }
   }
</script>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <person :firstName="a" :lastName="b"></person>
</template>
```

- Local component registration

  ```
  <script>
  import Person from './Person'
  export default {
     data() {
         return {
             a: "A",
             b: "B"
         }
     },
     components: { Person }
  }
  </script>
  ```
- Global component registration

  ```
  <script>
  import Person from './Person'
  import Vue from 'vue'

  Vue.component('person', Person);

  export default {
     data() {
         return {
             a: "A",
             b: "B"
         }
     }
  }
  </script>
  ```